# Transpose to-date and from-date to consecutive calendar month increments

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

| Person | Status | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-31 |
| 1 | B | 2023-04-01 | 3999-12-31 |

I also have another balance table with aggregates on a monthly basis.

| Person | Value | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | value | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | value | 2023-03-01 |
| 1 | value | 2023-04-01 |
| 1 | value | 2023-05-01 |

What would be a smart way to join in the status values on a monthly increment so it appears as follows

| Person | Status | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | A | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | A | 2023-03-01 |
| 1 | B | 2023-04-01 |
| 1 | B | 2023-05-01 |

Keen on thoughts!

I have tried some different joins but cant get it right. I am sure there is a smart way of doing this.

Comment: have a look at unpivot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `inner join` :

```
select t.Person, t.Status, b.Period
from mytable t
inner join balance b on b.Period between t.FromDate and t.ToDate
```

Result :

```
Person  Status  Period
1       A       2023-01-01
1       A       2023-02-01
1       A       2023-03-01
1       B       2023-04-01
1       B       2023-05-01
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pfOSS054)